When opening a deeplink on ios I get directed to a "route_not_found" screen in Safari after opening the app
I have a react native app that I am trying to get deep links working for.  On android they work fine, and on iOS they work fine if and only if the user has fully killed the app.  If the user has the app open, or if they have the app in the background, then when clicking on the notification with the deep link it opens the app first, then opens safari and shows
"route_not_found"
any suggestions on how to fix are appreciated!
Including my AppDelegate.m url handlers below

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] handleOpenUrl:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] handleOpenUrl:url options:options];
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

